# Python PIP stuck in uninstalled python version

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I recently uninstalled `python 3.6` because I was having problems with having 2 versions (`3.6` and `3.8`) of python installed. But now that I have `python 3.6` uninstalled, pip does not work at all:

```
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"c:\users\natur\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\python.exe"  "C:\Users\natur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Scripts\pip.exe" ': The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I understand that the `pip.exe` file was in the `python 3.6` folder, and got deleted, but I also checked the `pip` option in the `python 3.8` installer, and checked again by repairing. How would I make the `pip` command point to the `pip.exe` in `python 3.8`?

Comment: Check to see if python36 is in your path.  If so, remove it.

Comment: What operating system? And what did you run to get this error?

Comment: @Brennan Windows 10,
`pip`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like environment variable issue, try removing python3.6 references from environment variable in this case it PATH:

```
import os
os.environ['PATH'] #will display environment variable for python3.6
os.environ['PATH'].remove('c:/path/to/python3.6')
```

and force install upgrade pip for 3.8.

```
python -m pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall pip #force upgrade
```